# How to call web api controller deployed in Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

We have deployed two APIs on Service Fabric cluster

- API 1 (Port 8485)
- API 2(Port 8630)

We are able to access the apis locally using following URL:

- http://localhost:8485/api/controller
- http://localhost:8630/api/controller

Service fabric cluster explorer is accessible using following URL

```
https://{MyLoadBalancerName}.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer
```

But, I am not able to access the API 1 by using following URL

```
https://{MyLoadBalancerName}.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8485/api/controller
```

I tried adding following Load balancing Rule

- Protocol: TCP
- Port: 80
- Backend Port: 8485

But no luck!
Can somebody please explain how to call api controller?

Comment: did you declare service endpoints of type 'http' in your service manifests?

Comment: @LoekD yes I have added the endpoints

Comment: you route 80 to 8485, so the first api should be accessible at "https://{MyLoadBalancerName}.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/controller" can you try that?

Comment: Are you able to open the service fabric explorer and see what endpoints your service in using.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add those ports in list of opened port when you creating cluster on azure. you can also add them after you created that cluster. check the link from documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/create-load-balancer-rule

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the above ports have access in NSG

[image]